# Music went off - word choice

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

If a speaker stops working all of a sudden, is it correct to say: "the music went off"? If not, what word would you use instead?

While we were performing, the music went off.

Comment: See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+music+went+off%2Cthe+music+stopped&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20music%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20music%20stopped%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***the music went off*** has virtually no currency compared to ***the music stopped***. There's also *the music **died** [off / away]*, which may have gained some currency from  "the day the music died" (a reference in [American Pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Pie_(song)) to the plane crash in 1959 when Buddy Holly died).

Comment: Very common in the UK. 'The music went off and we found it was because of a loose wire to the speaker'.

Comment: In fact, a typical UK casual user would probably omit 'because of'.

Comment: If the event happened 'while you were performing', the 'music' didn't go off, unless you stopped playing at exactly the same time. The amplified sound went off. Maybe you stopped playing the music a few moments later.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem right when speaking informally. Alternatively, you could say "the music stopped playing."